# Pointer value return to zero every loop

Tags: c++, pointers

Maybe this is a silly question, but after returning value to pointer and everything is good, when the `while` loop start again the value of pointer returning to zero

Here is the code:

```
int num;
    int size = 0;
    int **p = 0; /*Or 0*/

    while (true) {
        cout << "Choose number:\n\n";
        cout << "1- Print array\n";
        cout << "2- Enter new row to array\n";
        cout << "3- Delete a row from array\n";
        cin >> num;
        switch (num)
        {
        case 1:
            Print(p, size);
            break;
        case 2:
            p = Add(p, size);
            size++;
            break;
        case 3:
            p = Delete(p, size);
            size--;
            break;
        }
    }
```

why the pointer value disappeared?

Edite:

I debugged the code and the value of p is good until the loop start again, then it returns to null.
`Add` and `Delete` functions :

```
int **Add(int **pm, int size) {

    int arr[6];
    cout << "Enter 6 new elements to the row: ";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
    int **tmp = new int*[size + 1];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        tmp[i] == pm[i];
    }
    delete[]pm;
    pm = tmp;
    pm[size] = arr;

    return pm;
}

int **Delete(int **pm, int size) {
    int num;
    cout << "Enter row number to delete:";
    cin >> num;

    int**tmp = new int*[size - 1];
    for (size_t i = 0, j = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
    {
        if (i != num)
        {
            tmp[j] = pm[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    delete[]pm;
    pm = tmp;

    return pm;
}
```

Comment: Debug the value of p step-by-step. Also, in order to recieve a proper answer, supply the code of Add and Delete functions.

Comment: It is completely unclear what is being asked.

Comment: Why are you not using `std::vector` along with `std::shared_ptr`

Comment: because i still learning c++

Comment: learning c by trying to write c++ is a strange strategy, dont do it

Comment: Your `Add()` function is writing 6 elements of an array with only 2 elements.   That is undefined behaviour.

Comment: `pm[size] = arr;` Don't put a local variable into the array. The pointer value is not valid when the function returns.

Comment: The described problem can't be reproduced. See http://ideone.com/SNbq1t

Comment: Thanks @4386427 .. your answer is right .. put it in answers to give you rate